# Check subsite permission sharepoint online CSOM

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

Using Powershell, i am trying to get permissions of a subsite of my SharePoint online environment.

The site i am trying to get permission from is located at https://tenant.sharepoint.com/production.

I want to know which users or groups have access to this site.

I am using CSOM with Powershell to connect to my online environment.

Comment: I actually got it working using:

A PS script which is way too long to post here.........

Answer (score 0):

For getting list of *groups* you could consider the following example:

```
# Retrieve web groups
$groups = $context.Web.RoleAssignments.Groups
$context.Load($groups)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

In case of list of users for a particular web, it is not so straightforward  since `RoleAssignmentCollection` class does not expose `Users` property. Anyway the following example demonstrates how to *retrieve the list of users for a web site*:

```
Function Get-WebUsers() {
param(
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web = $(throw "Please provide a Web")
) 
   $ctx = $Object.Context
   $assignments = $context.Web.RoleAssignments
   $context.Load($assignments)
   $context.ExecuteQuery()

   $members = @()
   $assignments.GetEnumerator() | % { 
       $member = $context.Web.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipalId($_.PrincipalId).Member
       $context.Load($member)
       $members += $member
   }
   $context.ExecuteQuery()

   $users = @()
   $members | % { 
         if($_.PrincipalType  -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType]::User) {
             $users += $_
         } 
   }
   $users
}
```

Example:

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Function Get-Context([String]$WebUrl,$UserName,$Password) {
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebUrl)
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}


Function Get-WebUsers() {
param(
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web = $(throw "Please provide a Web")
) 
   $ctx = $Object.Context
   $assignments = $context.Web.RoleAssignments
   $context.Load($assignments)
   $context.ExecuteQuery()

   $members = @()
   $assignments.GetEnumerator() | % { 
       $member = $context.Web.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipalId($_.PrincipalId).Member
       $context.Load($member)
       $members += $member
   }
   $context.ExecuteQuery()

   $users = @()
   $members | % { 
         if($_.PrincipalType  -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType]::User) {
             $users += $_
         } 
   }
   $users
}


$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/news"
$Username = "jdoe@consoto.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = ""

$context = Get-Context -WebUrl $Url -UserName $Username -Password $Password

# Retrieve web groups
$groups = $context.Web.RoleAssignments.Groups
$context.Load($groups)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

write "Group names:"
$groups.GetEnumerator() | % { 
    $_.Title 
}

# Retrieve web users
$users = Get-WebUsers -Web $context.Web  
write "User names:"
$users | % { 
    $_.Title 
}

$context.Dispose()
```

Gist: [WebUsersAndGroups.ps1](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7ef20dc56a77c9440fd6ebeae0619721)